# JS/CSS: trying to apply color to <li> based on where scrolling in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `.body-text` div which has a bunch of content, with specific sections. As I scroll from one sub `<div>` in `.body-text` to another, I would like to apply a different color to an `<a>` tag in my navigation div, and similarly unapply a color to another `<a>`. How do I keep track of scrolling positions? Here is my pseudo real world scenario:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/r9cf7qu4/17/

When I go from `#cecil` to `#braxton` i would like to apply `color:yellow` to `#braxton_link` and make `#cecil` link white.

Comment: And where's your sample code.

Comment: @Mouser It's in the JSFiddle.

Comment: @TylerH, nope there you can find some HTML and CSS, but not his own attempt to write a system to changes the colors

Comment: Where are your attempts of doing this? Also, your menu doesn't move so when you scroll you won't see the change....

Comment: Read my solution to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394485/highlight-active-menu-item-on-scroll/28394701#28394701, it should give you some inspiration to solve your problem.

Comment: @Mouser thank you for the inspiration of approach. I basically 100% cribbed your solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/r9cf7qu4/17/ ,however I have two issues: 1) why do you add in addition to `refElement.top` and `refElement.height` the height of the wrapper as the upper bound? One would assume the sum of the refElement height and its top position would be a sufficient upper bound for windowPos as it bounds by the desired `refElement`. what additionally are you adding?2) When I implement it with or without that change I seem to be missing something as It doesnt work, currently